# How to download excel file using storage disk('s3')

Tags: javascript, php, vue.js, laravel-5, storage

recently i am having problem in downloading file using storage disk('s3') in laravel .
I can download file using export.php but i need to convert it to use s3, for which i can't find help on chrome .Here is my code

```
if ($request->download && !is_null($data)) {
                    $array = json_decode( json_encode($data), true);    
                    $final_array = [];
                    foreach($array as $key){
                        unset($key['id']);
                        array_push($final_array,$key);  
                    }
                    $keys = array_keys(($final_array[0]));
                    $file_name = 'Today_Delivery_'.$request->user()->id.'_'.Carbon::now()->format('d_M_Y_His').'.xlsx';
                    (new GenDataExport(collect(json_decode(json_encode($final_array), true)), $keys ))->store($file_name);

                    // $s3 = \Storage::disk('s3');
                    // $filePath = '/users/signatures'.'/'.$user_id.'/post-'.$customer_id.'_'.$imageFileName;
                    // $s3->put($filePath, file_get_contents($image), 'public');
                    // $url = config('filesystems.disks.s3.arn_url');
                }
```

As you can see the file is downloading by export.php file and i want to use the commented code to download it , but can't think where to use that code .Any help will be appreciated ,Thanks.

i tried but got this error

file_get_contents() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, array given

when i gave $final_array to file_get_contents
Here is my $final_array value

```
 [0] => Array
        (
            [customer_name] => doodh walah
            [area] => no area
            [product_name] => milk bill
            [address] => 
            [qty] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [customer_name] => doodh walah
            [area] => no area
            [product_name] => milk
            [address] => 
            [qty] => 1
        )
```